# How to move all coins from 3D space to a corner of 2D canvas

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make a game like temple run 2. I want the same effect as stated in question and as attached screenshot. I tried with Animation its working when I animate the coin to center top but no luck with top left corner. Please Help.
Thanks

Here is code:

```
if (col.gameObject.tag == "500") {
    score = CryptograpicEncryption.GetInt ("ScoreKey") + pick500;
    CryptograpicEncryption.SetInt ("ScoreKey", score);
    ScoreCount.text = "Cash Collected: " + CryptograpicEncryption.GetInt ("ScoreKey").ToString ();
    col.gameObject.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetTrigger ("openNote");
    col.gameObject.transform.GetChild (1).GetChild (1).gameObject.SetActive (false);
    col.gameObject.GetComponent<Animator> ().SetTrigger ("highLeft");
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on your game but here are some options:

1. Add an empty gameobject to your character and carefully set its position so that it always be positioned behind the desired ui object. Then move the coins from 3d space into the 3d space position of the game object.
2. Remove the coin as soon as the player get it, then create an identical coin using UI.Image in its place (in 2d space of canvas) immediately moving to the corner of canvas. You can convert 3d space position to 2d using `2dPosition = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(3dPosition)`
3. You can calculate the 3d position of the corner of the canvas using `3dPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(2dPosition)` and make the coins follow that location. But the location changes overtime as the camera moves so you should recalculate it every frame.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. #2 Sounds like an answer. I will wait some more time to get more options if its there any. Otherwise I will accept your answer.

Comment: @JamshaidAlam Yep #2 would be the most appropriate route. There's an infinite number of positions in 3D that your 2D element overlaps, so it would be much harder to select a suitable position in 3D to "send" a 3D coin to. I.e. you would presumably want it to appear roughly the same size at all times, which would likely involve some tricky projection maths.

Comment: Thanks LukeBriggs and @Bijan. I am accepting this answer since #2 is the best option to achieve this issue. Cheers!